# Does the addition of water to N2H4 produce N2H4

Tags: acid-base, erratum

I am currently calculating the $\ce{pH}$ of a species.

The reaction is as follows,

$$\ce{N2H4 + H2O <=> N2H_{$A$}+ + OH-}$$

However, I'm not sure what the value of $A$ will be. In my textbook it says $4$, which is stumping me as in every other example with a weak base the subscript increases.

What is the value of $A$ and why?

Comment: A little nonsense in a textbook is good for you; it puts your mental immune system on alert. You know that equations must be _balanced_, right?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, equations must be balanced, thus the only correct way to write this is:

$$\ce{N2H4 + H2O <=> N2H5+ + OH-}$$

Easy to remember: Nitrogen typically has a free electron pair which can act as a Lewis base for a proton.

If your textbook says $4$, it is an error in your book. Good job on spotting it and realising it.